# Calling Rust from C++ using CXX Bridge

Tags: c++, rust

I am trying to build an application where C++ is the host language and where some functions implemented in Rust are called from C++.

Like all applications, this one, too, has a unique main entry point called main().

As I am new to Rust and CXX Bridge, the problem I'm facing is that all sample code I have found on Google implements this main() function in the Rust part of the project, while I want it implemented in the C++ part of it.

For debugging purposes and as a workaround, I have added a function cppmain() in the C++ code. The Rust main() then calls that cppmain() which in turn calls the Rust function I want to test:

`User launches app --> app entered at Rust main() --> C++ cppmain() --> Rust test function`

This works for testing but is not what I ultimately need.

What I ultimately want is to remove the Rust main(), and in exchange make cppmain() the official main() of the application (essentially by renaming it to main()):

`User launches app --> app entered at C++ main() --> Rust test function`

However, I have not succeeded in this. The CXX Bridge seems to expect a main.rs file with the Rust main() inside, and if this is not the case, the build fails (using cargo).

If somebody knows how to solve this problem please let me know. Thanks, Mario

Comment: I don't know about CXX Bridge in particular, but if the Rust part of your code has no `main.rs` then maybe it should be set up as library crate.

Comment: If "some functions" means there is a small amount of rust functions called, it would probably be easier to just create a library in rust with a well defined C API and call this C API from C++.

Answer (score 1):

So this is mainly a build question. [CXX](https://docs.rs/cxx) doesn't have any preference for whether the entrypoint of your application is in Rust or C++ or elsewhere. You mostly find sample code for CXX with `main()` in Rust because that's all you can do with Cargo, which is a Rust build system.

If you want to build a C++ binary with some functions implemented in Rust, then you need to first build your Rust source as a library and then link it into your C++ binary.

Bigger projects will often have their own multi-language build systems (Bazel, GN, Buck, etc.) that would make this more straightforward, but you can do it yourself just with Cargo or rustc (your Rust toolchain) and a C++ compiler & linker (Clang, GCC, i.e. your C++ toolchain).

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#the-crate-type-field for the Cargo side of things. You will want a library crate with a `crate-type` of `staticlib`, which will produce a `.a` archive file that you can then link into a larger C++ program.

Comment: I'm happy to believe CXX is agnostic as to whether the entry point is in Rust or C++. It's just that I can't find a code sample and would highly appreciate to get hold of one. Said that, I think I have to look again and more closely into what exactly CXX actually does